# How to check if a TCP socket is still connected in C?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, error-handling, network-programming

I am building a Distributed File system using TCP Sockets in C. I have to distribute a file and send it to four servers from the client code I have written. I was wondering if there is a systematic way to check if the connection to a specific server is still alive.

Some additional information:
1.) Both the server and client codes in C are written by me.
2.) I issued a connect() call for all the servers at the start of my client code (and it was successful).
3.) I don't wish to attempt to read or write data on that socket to check its status.
I intend to handle that situation where a server is suddenly shut down.

Comment: Sending data is the only way to know for sure immediately, in my experience. Otherwise it can take several minutes.

Comment: Otherwise it can take forever.